# How to Store and Retrieve Image in SQL Server VARBINARY(MAX) datatype

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have saved an image in SQL DB, Image field of varbinary(max) datatype in the following way.

```
$image = "baby.jpg";
$type = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($image);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
$insert = "insert into logoType(image)values(?)";
$param = array($base64);
$sql = sqlsrv_query($dbhandle, $insert, $param ) or die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors()) );
```

The insertion part is successful. Now, how can I retrieve the saved image from database and display it in webpage using php. I have tried the following method, but kept getting the error message, "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors."

```
header('Content-Type: image/x-bmp');
echo $image;
```

How can an image be displayed in webpage using php with the data stored in db?. Please Guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've converted the image to Base64 before saving, so you should convert it back and then use `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<?php
    $serverName = "server";
  $uid = "user";
  $pwd = "pass";
  $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
         "PWD"=>$pwd,
         "Database"=>"database");
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
  
  if( $conn === false ){
    echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }
  
   $fotoquery = "SELECT column_image FROM Table WHERE Column = 'xxxxxxxxxx'";
   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $fotoquery);
 
    if( $stmt === false ){
           echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
           die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    
   $dataImage = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
   $varimg = base64_encode($dataImage[0]);
   $data = base64_decode($varimg);
         $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
   
  if ($im !== false) {
   header('Content-Type: image/png');
   imagepng($im);
   imagedestroy($im);
  }
  else {
   echo 'An error occurred.';
  }
?>
```