# How to save images in MSSQL using Laravel 5

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm trying to save an image into my MSSQL database (BLOB) using Laravel.

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeImages (EmplNr, Name, Image)
VALUES(1011, 'John Doe' ,  (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\mypath\John_Doe.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) rs))
```

This is working in SQL Server Management Studio.

Now i would like to make the same insert in Laravel 5.4.

I created a model and a controller.

model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'EmployeeImages';

    protected $primaryKey = 'EmplNr';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['EmplNr', 'Name', 'Image'];
}
```

and the controller(store method):

```
public function store()
    {

        $file = request()->file('avatar');

        $ext = $file->guessClientExtension();

        $nameWithExt = request('name') . '.' . $ext;

        $file->storeAs('avatars', $nameWithExt);

        Employee::create([

            'EmplNr' => request('emplNr'),
            'Name' => request('name'),
            'Image' => '' // what should i do here ?

        ]);   

        return back();

    }
```

i tried to do something like this:

```
Employee::create([
    'EmplNr' => request('emplNr'),
    'Name' => request('name'),
    'Image' => 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N"C:\mypath\ccup\storage\app\avatars\{$nameWithExt}", SINGLE_BLOB) rs' 

]);
```

but this is not working. Do have anybody any idea how to solve it. I need to save the image not the path in database!

Comment: I think you should store path of image into database

Comment: you can try using DB::raw()

Answer (score -1):

The file path that works when you execute the SQL on the SQL server is to an image that is on that SQL Server disk.

If you want to do it this way, then you need to get laravel to save the, presumably, uploaded image to a known location on the SQL server.

You might be able to make this work, but it's a bad idea in so many ways. Try sending the SQL server an array of bytes that is the image data instead - see [How to Store and Retrieve Image in SQL Server VARBINARY(MAX) datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400767/how-to-store-and-retrieve-image-in-sql-server-varbinarymax-datatype) for an example

Comment: I'm convertig a simple .jpeg file with `file_get_contents` and encode it with `base64_encode` but unfortunetly is to the same string like in my database. In PHP: 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAh4AAAIwCAYAAADJZWIMAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwE.....' and in MSSQL is something like this: '0xFFD8FFE1001845786966000049492A000800000000000000' I think the concodig is different. How to get the same encoding ?

Comment: some legacy database that used with desktop app require developer to read and write the data to sql server, and it's still a norm in industries to use it.